# How do i get a program that takes measurement to change the interval it takes after a time ,i am using time.sleep(num) to enter the interval?

Tags: python, time, intervals

I have a program that takes measurement after a time delay that the user inputs.However I would want the interval to be adjusted say after the time one hour measurements being taken

I have tried to time the whole program and then manipulate the variable going into time.sleep() but this has led to some inaccuracies.

```
num=input('insert interval in minutes')
name=str(input('insert file name')

def instrumentcontrol():
  #has measurement commands to write and read data.

def dataoutput():
    results=pandas.Dataframe()
    results=results.append(data,ignore_index=True)
    results.to_csv('%s'%name)

def main():
    num=mum*60
    while True:
        instrumentcontrol()
        dataoutput()
        time.sleep(num)

main()
```

I want to say after running for an hour take interval of measurements at 5 min
and after running 2 hours 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I go through your code and i saw `num = mum*60` i think you are trying to convert sec into minutes please correct that `num = num*60` and let me know.

Comment: That part of the code allows user to enter the delay in minutes instead of seconds.